# Implementing an SSO platform between different server languages and platforms

Tags: c#, jsp, sso

Our company uses a 3rd party platform to manage a pretty large portion of our business, but the platform is built on top of JSP and MySQL. However, our own products are written in C#/.Net. We're currently researching methods of being able to implement an SSO between these two services without too much overhead. The SSO would pretty much be one-way, coming from the JSP project over to our C# web app.

I've been reading up on SSO, and there seems to be a lot of different information out there about what is best practice.

In production, we pretty much just want to be able to log in to the JSP project and click a link which will log us into our C# application, but I'm not finding a lot of information on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

There are two general ways to do an SSO:

### Point-to-point

- App A and App B share a secret key ahead of time.
- User signs on to App A using the existing signon page.
- App A needs to transfer control to App B,.
- App A generates a temporary SSO ticket and encrypts it using the secret.
- The ticket contains the user ID, a timestamp, custom metadata, and random padding (to thwart [known plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)).
- App A issues a redirect to AppB, passing the ticket.
- App B reads the ticket, decrypts it, and performs it own form of authentication using the ticket instead of any sort of password.
- Ticket expires within a short period (less than one minute).

### Enterprise

- You build a third system known as an [identity provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider).  Or you use an existing one, such as Google+ or Facebook, if that suits the business case.
- You remove authentication code from App A and App B and replace it with an integration with the identity provider.
- When a user needs to sign on to either app, the system redirects the user to a central authentication page (SSO page) where the user signs on, which checks identity against the identity provider and initiates a new session. He can then navigate to either App A or App B without having to enter his credentials again.
- Both App A and App B call services on the identity provider to confirm that the user is who he says he is and that a valid session is in flight.
- Neither App A nor App B have a signon page of their own.
- Two popular systems that support enterprise SSO are [OATH](https://oauth.net/2/) and [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language).
- This sort of setup may require a keep-alive mechanism to update the session sliding window.
- This is not trivial, but once you have it in place, it will scale well to include any systems introduced later.

### Hybrids

You can also combine the above, e.g. instead of an encrypted ticket and shared secret you could expose a identity provider service on one of the apps and the other app would integrate with it.  If you come up with a hybrid authentication system, I suggest you post it on [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/) to get the design reviewed.